# Java - Removing an item from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist, `private ArrayList<ImageData> imageData;`, and I want to remove an object I added to the `ArrayList` with `imageData.clear();`

Here's the code:

```
private ArrayList<ImageData> imageData;

    public void thing(){
    imageData.add(new ImageData(sprite.getRenderedImage(), x, y)); //ImageData is another class I created for storing the data of images. 

    image.Data.remove(what should I put here in order to remove new 
    ImageData(sprite.getRenderedImage(), x, y);
```

Comment: Save the reference to the variable, add that reference, and also remove that reference.
As in:
    ImageData img = new ImageData(sprite.getRenderedImage(), x, y);
    imageData.add(img);
    image.Data.remove(img);

Comment: ArrayList.remove will only work if the Object implements .equals in such a way that the object you're trying to remove is `.equal` to the one that's in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Do Below

```
public void thing(){
ImageData newData = (new ImageData(sprite.getRenderedImage(), x, y);
imageData.add(newData); //ImageData is another class I created for storing the data of images. 

imageData.remove(newData ) 
ImageData(sprite.getRenderedImage(), x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
imageData.remove(imageData.size() -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to remove objects from an ArrayList:

```
remove(int index);
```

or

```
remove(Object o);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Sure you can remove by `subList(...).clear()` or other more complicated means but enumerating the simplest options seems appropriate.